# How to record the state of SVG as class in Illustrator?

Tags: class, svg, adobe-illustrator

In Adobe Illustrator I've designed a button with all sorts of elements in a single layer, lets call this 'State #1'. Then, I've duplicated that layer and made a number of colour changes and effects to the existing elements, lets called this 'State #2'.

How do I declare the state 1 and 2 as classes so I can change the state of the SVG on a webpage? IE. Default state is #1, on hover, change to state #2.

Also, is this the right way of designing classes/changes to the same layer/elements?[image]

No additional elements, just changes is colour and effects.

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in Adobe Illustrator or are you fine with editing the raw svg?

Comment: I'm new to SVG and Illustrator so I guess I'm looking for the 'normal' / 'best practice' method of doing it. However it would be convenient to do it all in Illustrator i suppose.

Comment: I have no clue about Illustrator. However, if you check the svg source, and identify the `<g>` tag that corresponds to your layer, you can just add a class manually: `<g class="foobar">`.